# Laravel validation "password" - error "The password is incorrect." in production

Tags: laravel, validation

There is a rule for checking the password - "password".
Everything works on the local server.
On the production server, it gives an "invalid password" error.

The password is exactly correct, because used to login. And the error is displayed when asking to confirm the action

```
'current-password' => ['required', 'password'],
```

Comment: I know. Standard Authentication

Comment: @TimLewis Yes it does, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-password

Comment: @JoelHinz I stand corrected! Apologies, I hadn't seen that rule before.